# Input.touchCount will not reset to 0 as a result of this one line of code

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

`Vector2 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);`

I am not sure why but using this line for me is making input.touchCount stay at 1. Any idea why this could be? I am posting the full script and I know it's not the best way of doing things but please focus on the main issue. :)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class MoveByTouch : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float musicSet = 0;
    public bool start = false;
    public GameObject removeText, enemeySpawn, timer, music;

    public bool gameStart = false;
    private TrailRenderer trail;

    public void GameStarted()
    {
        gameStart = true;
        Debug.Log("done");
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        music.SetActive(false);
        trail = GetComponent<TrailRenderer>();
        trail.enabled = false;
    }
    
    

    void Update()
    {
        

        if (gameStart == true)
        {
            
            Vector2 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);

            transform.position = touchPosition;
            start = true;
            trail.enabled = true;
            
            musicSet++;
            if (musicSet == 1)
            {
               music.SetActive(true);
            }
        }
        
        if(gameStart == false && start == true)
        {
            GameObject.Find("Player").SendMessage("endGame");

            music.SetActive(false);
        }

        Debug.Log(Input.touchCount);
    }

    
}
`
```

Comment: Does it ever come back as 0? (In other words "are you sure your screen is problem free?)

Comment: Yes, removing this line of code will make everything work properly again. Would it help if I show you the full script? Also just tested it with a different android device.

Comment: Also thinking it might have to do with the fact that I actually have two objects with scripts using this line of code, BUT when this script shown above is called the object with the same code is removed from the scene.

Comment: So just tested to see if the other object was interfering, it is not. Still trying to find out why this is happening. If anyone has an ideas please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was that I cannot use the Input.GetTouch(0) position and at the same time Input.TouchCount changes to 0. I fixed this by checking if the game has started and by checking if the touch count was above 0. If both are true then the code Input.GetTouch(0) will run properly. :)